# String split since blank space

Tags: javascript, split, concatenation

I have a problem with the next code

```html
     html:'<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">'+
                '<label for="pedidonom">Name</label>'+
                  '<input type="text" value='+e.getAttribute("name")+' class="swal2-input" id="nombre" placeholder="Parisina">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">'+
                '<label for="pedidonom">Description</label>'+
                '<input type="text" class="swal2-input" id="description" placeholder="Parisina" value='+description+'> '+
                '<input type="hidden" value='+e.getAttribute("idlookup")+' class="swal2-input"  placeholder="Parisina">'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>',
```

The problem is that in `value='+description+'` only shows first word.

I print the var description in the console and shows the complete text I think I'm doing incorrect concatenation help please

Comment: `value="'+description+'"> '+`, but really, don't use `.innerHTML`. You'll have to attach to DOM before you can assign Events. Poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the " " in every value, it could  be value=" '+e.getAttribute(\"name\")+' " and you must escape the quote marks, perhaps it will help you if you use **temple quotes**, so you would end with something like this:

```
html:`<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label for="pedidonom">Name</label>
          <input type="text" value="${e.getAttribute('name')}" class="swal2-input" id="nombre" placeholder="Parisina">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label for="pedidonom">Description</label>
          <input type="text" class="swal2-input" id="description" placeholder="Parisina" value="${description}">
          <input type="hidden" value="${e.getAttribute('idlookup')}" class="swal2-input"  placeholder="Parisina">
        </div>
      </div>`
```

Temple quotes let you write blocks of code or format texts without the need to close and open string quotes, and you can interpolate variables in the text using ${variableName}.

Hope it helps.